# How to get information about ZIP files?

Tags: compression, zip

i working on ClamAV antivirus database.
ZMD one of clamav database file who store information about malice's zip file.
i need to get this information from zip file but if possible not use any component

is encryption.
normal size
compressed size 
CRC32
compression method

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unzip -l` to list the contents or you can write your own zip format decoder to extract the information from the headers.  The format is documented in the [.ZIP File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).